# How to preserve default umask if renaming a tempfile

Tags: python, django

On a Django application, I create a tempfile. This temp file is created with the "0700" permissions. However, I need to rename that tempfile without keeping the permissions of the tempfile (0700), but want the file to obtain the permissions of the user (umask). I do not want to change the permissions of the file.

Is this possible?

Sample code:

```
import tempfile, os
content = "hello"
temp_fd, filename = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix=".tmp", prefix="test1", dir="/tmp")
with os.fdopen(temp_fd, "wb") as f:
        f.write(content)
os.rename(filename,"/home/user/testfile")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    # query current umask by replacing it
    old_umask = os.umask(0)

    # immediately restore the umask
    os.umask(old_umask)

    fd, tmp_file_path = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix='.%s.' % os.path.basename(self._file_path), dir=directory)

    # calculate the octal chmod and chmod the temp file
    octal_file_chmod = int('666', 8) & ~old_umask
    os.chmod(tmp_file_path, octal_file_chmod)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`shutil.move`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) should keep the permissions, but I am not sure how it is implemented, maybe you have to use a combination of [`shutil.copy2`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) and [`os.remove`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.remove).